# Как создать этот SVG эффект?

Tags: svg, svg-animation

Как мне создать SVG анимацию, как на этой странице http://edwindejongh.co/? Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, какие-нибудь ресурсы или объясните, что я должна сделать, чтобы воссоздать такую же страницу?

Comment: Это с тем-же успехом можно сделать без svg. Это же простые трансформации - поворот/масштабирование.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Загляните в стили и скрипты сайта!!! <kbd>F12</kbd>  в Chrome

Как для старта:

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  $('.intro__boxes').addClass('animate');
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.intro__boxes').addClass('no-transitions');
    $('.intro__boxes').addClass('fade-out');
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('.intro__boxes').removeClass('animate');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.intro__boxes').removeClass('no-transitions');
        $('.intro__boxes').removeClass('fade-out');
        intro.init();
      }, 10);
    }, 1000);
  }, 25000);
}, 100);
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.rect {
    x: 50%;
    y: 50%;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    fill: none;
    transform-origin: 50% 50% 0;
    transition: all 25s linear;
}

.rect1 {
  opacity: 0.3;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) rotate(-15deg) scale(1);
}

.animate .rect1 {
  opacity: 0.4;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) rotate(-11deg) scale(1.2);
}

.rect2 {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) rotate(0deg) scale(1);
}

.animate .rect2 {
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) rotate(10deg) scale(1.2);
}

.rect3 {
  opacity: 0.6;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) rotate(-75deg) scale(1);
}

.animate .rect3 {
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) rotate(-80deg) scale(1.5);
}

.rect4 {
  opacity: 0.8;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) rotate(-60deg) scale(0.77);
}

.animate .rect4 {
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) rotate(-75deg) scale(1.34);
}

.rect5 {
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) rotate(-45deg) scale(0.77);
}

.animate .rect5 {
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) rotate(-75deg) scale(1.49);
}

.rect6 {
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) rotate(-60deg) scale(1);
}

.animate .rect6 {
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) rotate(-90deg) scale(2);
}

.rect7 {
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) rotate(-75deg) scale(1);
}

.animate .rect7 {
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0) rotate(-125deg) scale(2.66);
}

.intro__boxes.no-transitions .rect {
  transition-duration: 0s;
}

.mask {
    fill: #01051a;
}

.intro__boxes {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    perspective: 600px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #18f2e0 0%, #183df2 100%);
    transition: opacity 1s cubic-bezier(0.15, 0.005, 0.155, 1);
}

.intro__boxes.animate {
  opacity: 1;
}

.intro__boxes.fade-out {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  
<div class="intro__boxes">
<svg width="100%" height="100%">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"></rect>
      <rect x="50%" y="50%" width="500" height="500" class="rect rect1"></rect>
      <rect x="50%" y="50%" width="500" height="500" class="rect rect2"></rect>
      <rect x="50%" y="50%" width="500" height="500" class="rect rect3"></rect>
      <rect x="50%" y="50%" width="650" height="650" class="rect rect4"></rect>
      <rect x="50%" y="50%" width="650" height="650" class="rect rect5"></rect>
      <rect x="50%" y="50%" width="750" height="750" class="rect rect6"></rect>
      <rect x="50%" y="50%" width="1128" height="1128" class="rect rect7"></rect>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect class="mask" mask="url(#mask)" width="100%" height="100%"></rect>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Я смотрела, но разобраться не могла, так как SVG для меня ещё в новинку. Спасибо вам огромное за помощь!